# How to convert a hexadecimal value to ASCII?

Tags: vb.net, hex, ascii

I am trying to use fstream to write an executable file:

```
Dim buffer As String
Dim c As Char = Chr(9)
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream("test.exe", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
Dim w As System.IO.BinaryWriter = New System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs)

w.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
w.Write(HEX VALUES HERE)

w.Close()
fs.Close()
```

To convert the hex to ASCII I have tried things such as:

```
  MessageBox.Show(ChrW(Convert.ToInt32("48", 16)))
  MessageBox.Show(Chr(CInt("&H" & "48")))
  MessageBox.Show(Chr(CInt("&H48")))
```

However each of those functions will only work with a single character. How do I make those functions work for entire strings?

Answer (score 7):

I am posting another answer. You can use the below code to implement your functionality.

```
Dim st As String = "49204c6f76652050726f6772616d6d696e672e"
    Dim com As String
    For x = 0 To st.Length - 1 Step 2
        Dim k As String = st.Substring(x, 2)
        com &= System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(k, 16)).ToString()
    Next
```

You can also use the below code function:

```
Dim st As String = "49204c6f76652050726f6772616d6d696e672e"
Dim com As String
For x = 0 To st.Length - 1 Step 2
    com &= ChrW(CInt("&H" & st.Substring(x, 2)))
Next
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to convert a hexadecimal string to ASCII:

```
Dim hexValue = "48"
Dim ASCII_value = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexValue, 16))
```

Comment: Maybe you completely missed the point of my question... How do I do it with MULTIPLE characters? If I say "Dim hexValue = "48&49" it doesn't work... If I add a space between the two it still doesn't work...How do I make it work for a whole string? (Or just two hex bytes eg "48 49")

Comment: @43.52.4D. You will need to create your own method and parse your string to build the ascii result you are expecting

Comment: I know what you want to do. It is very simple with this sample code to convert HEX to ASCII. I am giving you the tip to work on that. You should use For Loop to generate the ASCII from HEX. Here above my answer is right & it can work and give you the ASCII values.

Comment: Hey man thanks, but I already wrote code just like yours previous to your answer... It works fine except for if you type a hex value such as "80"... It will write it as "3F" which is "?" How do I get around this?

Comment: Did you convert into ASCII, using "80" & "3F"?

Answer (score 1):

I've collected various Hex functions and changed them till they worked.
Here they are:

http://pastebin.com/ewQh5iRa

Answer (score 1):

Converting H to hexadecimal:

        debug.Print hex(asc("H"))
    >48

    Back to get H again:

        debug.Print chr(val("&H" & "48"))
    >H

> Let me send more details giving a simple example. **Remember your answer is how to convert hex to ascii.** For it, you just need to get function hex_to_ascii described bellow.

```
Sub test()
Dim str_word As Variant
str_word = "Hello Word"
Debug.Print "We've set=" & str_word

Dim hex_word As Variant
hex_word = str_to_hex(str_word)
Debug.Print "Just for convert to Hex format=" & hex_word
'48656C6C6F20576F7264

Dim ascii_word As Variant
ascii_word = hex_to_ascii(hex_word)
Debug.Print "Getting ASCII format from Hex=" & ascii_word
'072101108108111032087111114100

Dim hex_word_from_ascii As Variant
hex_word_from_ascii = ascii_to_hex(ascii_word)
Debug.Print "Finally converting Hex value to ascii=" & hex_word_from_ascii
'48656C6C6F20576F7264

Dim str_from_hex As Variant
str_from_hex = hex_to_str(hex_word_from_ascii)
Debug.Print "Remember=" & str_from_hex
'Hello Word
End Sub

Function str_to_hex(p_str As Variant) As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim resp As Variant
Dim tmp As String
For x = 1 To Len(p_str)
  tmp = Mid$(p_str, x, 1)
  resp = resp & Hex(Asc(tmp))
Next
str_to_hex = resp
End Function

Function hex_to_str(p_hex As Variant) As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim resp As Variant
Dim tmp As String
For x = 1 To Len(p_hex) Step 2
  tmp = Mid$(p_hex, x, 2)
  resp = resp & Chr(Val("&H" & tmp))
Next
hex_to_str = resp
End Function

Function hex_to_ascii(p_hex As Variant) As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim resp As Variant
Dim tmp As String
For x = 1 To Len(p_hex) Step 2
  tmp = Mid$(p_hex, x, 2)
  resp = resp & Format(Val("&H" & tmp), "000")
Next
hex_to_ascii = resp
End Function

Function ascii_to_hex(p_ascii As Variant) As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim resp As Variant
Dim tmp As String
For x = 1 To Len(p_ascii) Step 3
  tmp = Mid$(p_ascii, x, 3)
  resp = resp & Hex(tmp)
Next
ascii_to_hex = resp
End Function
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in more detail, so others can understand.

Answer (score 0):

**Tried and tested code**

Create a function by copy pasting this

```
Function HexToString(ByVal hex As String) As String
    Dim text As New System.Text.StringBuilder(hex.Length \ 2)
    For i As Integer = 0 To hex.Length - 2 Step 2
        text.Append(Chr(Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16)))
    Next
    Return text.ToString
End Function
```

Use it like this

```
Debug.WriteLine(HexToString("73696D306E"))
```

[Source](https://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/vbnet-hex-to-string-conversion/)

Answer (score 0):

Sort of redundant, but I'll add something I find simpler.  This is used when you have a byte array.

```
Dim str As String = String.Empty
For Each c In byteArray
    str &= ChrW(c)
Next
```