# How to convert hex to char in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I can convert from byte to hex but I have problem with converting from hex to char.

Below my code for converting from byte to hex:

```
 Dim RXByte As Byte
    Do
        RXCnt = 0
        Do
            RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte >> 4) 
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte And 15)
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            RXArray(RXCnt) = " "
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            SpaceCount = (SpaceCount + 1) And 31     
            If SpaceCount = 0 Then                    
                RXArray(RXCnt) = Chr(13) ' CR
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
                RXArray(RXCnt) = Chr(10) ' LF
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            Else
                If (SpaceCount And 3) = 0 Then       
                    RXArray(RXCnt) = " "
                    RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
                    RXArray(RXCnt) = " "
                    RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop Until (COMPort.BytesToRead = 0)
        '----- End of communication protocol handling -------------------------------------------------------------
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display)) 
    Loop Until (COMPort.BytesToRead = 0)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a hexadecimal value to ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017007/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-value-to-ascii)

Comment: What do you mean by converting from byte to hex, and [how is it related to this code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640)? A byte is a number, hex is the same number in a human readable form that computers don't need or want, and there is the `Hex()` function that does the conversion.

Comment: i want to convert from hex to string in vb.net

Comment: What is the code in the `Display` method? We need to see that to be sure that we can tell you to forget about the `LookUpTable` code and simply put the bytes read into a List(Of Byte) then use `Dim s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(yourList.ToArray())`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nUT6SCAr that my full code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the lookup table. Just use the built-in function to convert a byte to a string.

```
    b = 245
    s = b.ToString("X")
```

There's some function the to the opposite.

```
    s = "F4"
    b = Convert.ToByte(s, 16)
```

I would also suggest you use a string builder instead of the array you are using.

Comment: can you tell me how to put that code into my coding, sorry because first time to create program, thanks