# Replace all hex encoding in string with equivalent ASCII value

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that contains hex values inside brackets []. I need to find all those strings and replace them with the decoded values (ASCII).

Example input: Help[2f]me[2f]with[2d]this[2e]question

Desired output: Help/me/with-this.question

I have used regex expression but could not find the right way to convert to ASCII by itself. The input value is dependent on a textbox and it will have multiple []s in the string, so the following code that I wrote does not work because the input character has to be the ASCII of hex inside [].

```
Dim input As String = "Hello[2f]world"
Dim replacement As String = "/"
Dim expression As String = "\[(.*?)\]"
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, expression, replacement)

MsgBox(result)
```

Update:

```
    Dim Input As String = "Hello[1B][84][01][81][84][85]World"
    Dim expression As String = "\[.*?\]"
    Dim result = Regex.Replace(Input, expression, Function(m)
                                                      Return Convert.ToChar(
                                                          System.Convert.ToUInt64(
                                                              m.Value.Trim({"["c, "]"c}), 16
                                                          )
                                                      )
                                                  End Function)

    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result)
    TCPClientz.Client.Send(sendbytes)
```

I am trying to send the ASCII Character to TCP/IP port, the printer with IP only accepts ASCII Character, since all ASCII character are not writeable I was writing Hex value inside bracket and converting it into ASCII before sending to TCP/IP port but some of the command have [84],[81],[85].

I sent an email to printer manufacture and this is  their response:

The printer uses extended ASCII table. You program may not be sending character out over 127 decimal. I believe these is a setting in VB for extended ASCII must be turned on.

Comment: [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) is not precise: you'll need to find out exactly which character set is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Regex.Replace, you can use an "match evaluator function" for the replacement:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Public Function HexToChar(m As Match) As Char
        Return Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(m.Value.Trim("[]".ToCharArray()), 16))
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = "Hello[2f]world[41][42][43]"
        Dim expression As String = "\[.*?\]"
        Dim evaluator As MatchEvaluator = AddressOf HexToChar
        Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, expression, evaluator)

        Console.WriteLine(result)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
Hello/worldABC
```

If you really want to, you can in-line the function:

```
Dim result = Regex.Replace(input, expression, Function(m)
                                                  Return Convert.ToChar(
                                                      System.Convert.ToUInt32(
                                                          m.Value.Trim({"["c, "]"c}), 16
                                                      )
                                                  )
                                              End Function)
```

---

References:

- [Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator))
- [How to convert a hexadecimal value to ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017007/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-value-to-ascii)

Comment: This is doing the right thing but when there is [84], the output is ?, why is this happening

Comment: how can i get this working with Extended ASCII character as well? @Andrew Morton

Comment: @RanjanSapkota What sounds like a small change makes it a completely different question!

Comment: @RanjanSapkota Do you mean Windows code page 1252?

Comment: https://www.garykessler.net/library/ascii.html       this link have a Extended ASCII Character, i am not sure what is windows code page 1252 @Andrew Morton

Comment: @RanjanSapkota Not knowing what you are asking for is not a good start ;)

Comment: @RanjanSapkota Can you compare the page you linked to with other character sets to find out the actual name? "Extended ASCII" is not the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to my earlier answer, what you are asking for is probably regarding the data as having the [ISO-8859-1 encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8).

This assumes that the input string is correct:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input As String = "Hello[2f]world[83][B1][B6][F0]"

    Dim bb As New List(Of Byte)
    Dim i = 0

    While i < input.Length
        If input(i) = "[" Then
            Dim x = input.Substring(i + 1, 2)
            bb.Add(Convert.ToByte(x, 16))
            i += 4
        Else
            bb.Add(CByte(Asc(input(i))))
            i += 1
        End If
    End While

    ' Show some representation of the data, possibly
    ' not correct for every character:
    Dim enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
    Dim result = enc.GetString(bb.ToArray())
    Console.WriteLine(result)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
Hello/worldƒ±¶ð
```

Now, as you want to send binary data to the printer, just send the bytes of `bb.ToArray()` - there's no need to do the Encoding step if I am reading that part of the question correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help but my desired output is different then what you did, I have updated the question

Comment: @RanjanSapkota Please see the last paragraph which I added to this answer.